# How to add modulemap file to XCFramework manually?

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

I have an XCFramework which has the following directory structure:

```
.
└── WechatOpenSDK-XCFramework.xcframework
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── README.txt
    ├── ios-arm64_armv7
    │   ├── Headers
    │   │   ├── WXApi.h
    │   │   ├── WXApiObject.h
    │   │   └── WechatAuthSDK.h
    │   ├── Modules
    │   │   └── module.modulemap
    │   └── libWechatOpenSDK.a
    └── ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
        ├── Headers
        │   ├── WXApi.h
        │   ├── WXApiObject.h
        │   └── WechatAuthSDK.h
        ├── Modules
        │   └── module.modulemap
        └── libWechatOpenSDK.a
```

I added the `Modules` directory and the `module.modulemap` file manually. The XCFramework did not originally contain these.

For the `module.modulemap` file, I tried defining it as:

```
framework module WechatOpenSDK {
  umbrella header "WXApi.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

I also tried defining it as:

```
framework module WechatOpenSDK {
  header "WXApi.h"
  header "WXApiObject.h"
  header "WechatAuthSDK.h"

  export *
}
```

However, when I drag the XCFramework into another project, regardless of how I define the `module.modulemap` file, I can't get `import WechatOpenSDK` to work.

I also tried modifying the contents of the top-level `Info.plist` file in the XCFramework. I removed the `HeadersPath` property which had a value of `Headers`.

My question is: Is there a way to manually add modulemap support to this XCFramework?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the directory structure of your XCFramework and ignoring the `Modules` directories which you added manually, your XCFramework is packaging up a set of static libraries. Most likely you built it with the following command:

```bash
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library <path> [-headers <path>] [-library <path> [-headers <path>]...] -output <path>
```

Like you, I have experimented and failed to figure out a way to import a static library or an XCFramework which bundles up a set of static libraries as a module. I tried changing the `Defines Module` build setting of my static library to `YES`. I tried defining and adding the `module.modulemap` file manually in the following locations:

1. `MyLibrary.xcframework`
2. `MyLibrary.xcframework/Modules`
3. `MyLibrary.xcframework/<LibraryIdentifier>`
4. `MyLibrary.xcframework/<LibraryIdentifier>/Modules`
5. `MyLibrary.xcframework/<LibraryIdentifier>/Headers`

In the end, I gave up and came to the conclusion that we're best defining a dynamic framework and not a static library if we want to import it elsewhere as a module. Otherwise we're swimming against the Xcode tide. When you create a Framework target in Xcode and build it, you'll see that Xcode automatically gives it the following directory structure:

```
|-- MyFramework.framework (directory)
  |-- Info.plist (file)
  |-- MyFramework (binary file)
  |-- Headers (directory)
  |-- Modules (directory)
    |-- module.modulemap (file)
```

If you add a Swift file to your Framework target, you'll see that Xcode adds the following to the framework that gets built:

1. A `MyFramework-Swift.h` file in the `Headers` directory;
2. A `MyFramework.Swift` module in the `module.modulemap` file; and
3. A `MyFramework.swiftmodule` directory in the `Modules` directory.

Basically, Xcode does all the heavy lifting for us.

When you're ready to package up your set of frameworks as an XCFramework, use the following command to do so:

```bash
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework <path> [-framework <path>...] -output <path>
```